# GWT and templating engine

Tags: gwt, template-engine

I want to design a website using GWT. This is my understanding of how GWT pages will be delivered to the client browser - When the user puts in the URL into her browser she receives all the static HTML + GWT javascript, and then the javascript queries the server for the dynamic page content and adds it to the DOM. eg - For a blog page the content of the blog is queried by the javascript. is my understanding correct?

If I know that the content will surely be a part of the page(add does not depend on user clicking an expand button etc.), Will it be more efficient if the blog content was a part of the HTML initially served? Something that could be done by using a templating engine like django.
Is there a way to make a templating mechanism in GWT?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, putting your content into the HTML will reduce the number of round trips the client makes to your server. It also means that the blog content won't have to wait for your GWT javascript to load before it can be displayed.

GWT itself isn't useful for a template system, but most servers that run GWT servlets will also support JSP pages. GWT works fine with these pages, you just need to put the GWT script tag in as usual. You will no doubt be able to find a ready-made templating solution but rolling your own is [not too hard](http://www.jsptut.com/).